# Ruby creating instance variables outside a class

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

What does it mean to create an instance variable, say `@foo` in a file outside any class definition. Say there is a file, test.rb and the entire contents of the file are given below.

```
# test.rb
@foo = "bar"
puts @foo
```

It prints `"bar"`, but is this an instance variable in some sort of wrapping class?

Testing using two files indicates that there is a `main` object that everything is wrapped inside. Is this understanding correct?

*Contents of a.rb*

```
@me = self
@a = "from-a"
```

*Contents of b.rb*

```
require "./a"

@b = "from-b"
puts @me == self # true (self refers to the same object)
puts self.class  # Object
puts self.instance_variables # [@a, @b, @me]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Everything is an object in ruby. So you are actually in the `main` object right now, which is an instance of `Object`.

In your file, if you put `puts self.class`, you will see you are operating under `main`, and the class being `Object`.

Even in irb, for example:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > self
 => main 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > self.class
 => Object
```

Comment: Is `main` an instance of `Object` that everything operates under?

Comment: how is the main Object shared in a multi-user web application? e.g. let's say I have a file 'x.rb' I import in a Rails or Sinatra application. If one user requests calls a method in that file that sets @a = 5, and then another user calls a method in that file that retrieves @a, will the second user receive a value of 5? Or Do Rails/Sinatra create a separate instance of the Object class of that file for each separate user request?